# Send request out to a remote URL when a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery

We want to implement a pseudo link track for a couple links on our page and was curious how you can send a request to a remote URL (a beacon/link track) and also still forward the user to the next page, open a DIV, etc. Essentially onclick it can hit a remote URL behind the scenes to track what they clicked. Much like using Google Analytics, but this is app specific.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Pretty broad question, but you could send an Ajax request to the remote server and have something posted to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use jQuery to set up an onclick event on all anchor tags that submits the href value to your tracking page? Haven't tested it, but perhaps something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post('track.php?ref=' + encodeURI(href));
    });
});
```

---

If you only want to track certain links, you can add a class to the anchor. For example, add `class="track"` to your anchor tag combined with the jquery below.

```
$(function() {
    $("a.track").click(function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post('track.php?ref=' + encodeURI(href));
    });
});
```

Comment: By the way, if you only want it for a couple links on the page you can use set a class on the couple links you want to track and use a jquery class selector instead of the anchor tag selector.

Comment: What would we do if we didn't want it on all hrefs, just specific ones? Also, as far as you know this won't tie up any normal page processing right?

Comment: jeremy, as mentioned in my previous comment, you can apply classes to the links you want to track and use a class selector. will update example.

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't mess up normal page processing. Somebody smarter than me can probably tell you if there are any side effects of making the post ansynchronous (will it complete the tracking request if the page changes before the current page changes?)